# QGIS Browser - Location bar

Tags: qgis, qgis-browser

Is there a way to have a location bar (or breadcrumb trail) to show the location path in QGIS 3 browser panel? Most importantly in order to copy-paste a location and go to it directly without having to manually navigate the tree ...

Comment: Can't find anything, and I can't find a plugin that can tweak the browser. It might be possible with a python plugin but I'm not sure how the UI would work. Right click an item and get "Copy path to clipboard" would work one way. Maybe it needs a line item like the "filter" button generates....

Comment: Thanks @Spacedman, ineed for a second I thought I had found the way when I activated the filter button, but unfortunately it doesn't accepts path as filter. Then may be time to open a feature request :). Just wanted to make sure the functionality is not already existing but hidden somewhere..

Comment: I'm looking for the same feature. That's how I get around in ArcMap browser. Upvoting.

Comment: For reference, here is the feature request on GitHub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/36872

Answer (score 1):

This method works on Windows.

Right click on Favorites > Add a Directory > brings up a Windows Explorer window where you can paste or type a file path into the location bar

[image]

Click OK to add the filepath to the list of Favorite directories.

Comment: Thanks @csk, still not exactly what I was hoping for (I was more thinking of an ad-hoc, temporary navigation) but better than nothing. Also a feature to be taken directly to the file location (in QGI Browser) when clicking on the layer path in the Layer Properties > Information would be nice (sometimes files are so nested that is bore-some to navigate manually)

Comment: This is the feature that QGIS actually has. If you want new features, you can always make a feature request on their website.